# Panda3D's setInstanceCount(n) with Python

Tags: python, instance, panda3d

I've been looking for the answer for almost 2 days now and found nothing. I'm building a game with Panda3d engine and Python, and I wanted the floor to be tiled, so I was loading the 'grass' model as many times as I needed. When I play the game, though, it feels really really slow.

I found [this](https://www.panda3d.org/blog/hardware-geometry-instancing/) article that explained how `setInstanceCount(n)` worked, but I found no examples on how to use it nor how to access the IDs of the models that were copied.

I tried replacing `instanceTo()` in other programs with `setInstanceCount(n)`, but it doesn't seem like it is working.

```
dancer = Actor.Actor("chorus-line-dancer.egg", {"kick":"kick.egg"})
dancer.loop("kick")
dancer.setPos(0,0,0)
for i in range(50):
    placeholder = render.attachNewNode("Dancer-Placeholder")
    placeholder.setPos(i*5, 0, 0)
    dancer.setInstanceCount(5)
    #Original: dancer.instanceTo(placeholder)
```

How do I achieve this? Also, how do I access the data of each models, say, to set the coordinate? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the original `instanceTo()` instead. It's used for animation instancing, while `setInstanceTo` is used for rendering and setting geometry instances.